# ping, ssh work fine - NSLOOKUP gives error ** server can't find xxxxxx: NXDOMAIN

Tags: networking, 16.04, ssh, dns, ping

several hundred discussions around this problem, none exactly matching this issue
Mine is a Home network

Two nodes on a Home WiFi network(TOTOLINK)
(N1)maruti(192.168.1.15, bionic,18.x) & (N2)atal(192.168.1.4,xenial,16.x)

**/etc/resolv.conf on N1**

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search TOTOLINK
```

**/etc/resolv.conf on N2**

```
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search TOTOLINK
```

On N1

```
$ nslookup atal
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   atal
Address: 192.168.1.4
```

**Observation:**

ping, ssh between N1 & N2 work fine
nslookup on N1 work fine

**Problem:**

nslookup & host on N2 throw the following error

```
$nslookup maruti
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

** server can't find maruti: NXDOMAIN

$ host maruti
Host maruti not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

$ host 192.168.1.15
Host 15.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Comment: Are the entries in your `/etc/hosts` file? If so that'd explain why they can resolve in other contexts except for `nslookup`. Info here: https://serverfault.com/a/698060/11809